# how to hide template definition in header files of a static library

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I am building a static library wherein I am making use of generics by using templates. This is a sample template header file of the library to compute average

```
#ifndef AVERAGE_H_
#define AVERAGE_H_

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<numeric>

template<typename T>
class Average
{
public:
    std::vector<T> data;
    T getAvg();
};

template<typename T>
T Average<T>::getAvg()
{
    T sum=std::accumulate(data.begin(),data.end(),(T)0.0);

    return (T)(sum/data.size());
}

#endif /* AVERAGE_H_ */
```

Ans this is the sample application code where it is making use of the above library code

```
#include "Average.h"

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    Average<int> *objAvgInt = new Average<int> { };
    objAvgInt->data.push_back(1);
    objAvgInt->data.push_back(2);
    objAvgInt->data.push_back(3);
    objAvgInt->data.push_back(4);
    objAvgInt->data.push_back(5);
    objAvgInt->data.push_back(6);

    int avgInt=objAvgInt->getAvg();
    std::cout << "Int Avg= " << avgInt << std::endl;

    Average<float> *objAvgFloat = new Average<float> { };
    objAvgFloat->data.push_back(1);
    objAvgFloat->data.push_back(2);
    objAvgFloat->data.push_back(3);
    objAvgFloat->data.push_back(4);
    objAvgFloat->data.push_back(5);
    objAvgFloat->data.push_back(6);

    float avgFloat=objAvgFloat->getAvg();
    std::cout << "Float Avg= " << avgFloat << std::endl;
}
```

I know that we can't separate template declaration and definition into separate files(both has to be in header file), but this exposes my library code implementation to the third party user as the user needs library header files. So I want to know is it possible to create a library containing template definitions without exposing the implementation part of it to the third party user.

Comment: You can put the template definition in the `.cpp` file if you also make sure to explicitly instatiate all the version that are needed. If you don't know which ones you need beforehand the definition needs to be available in the header. Some people like to put the definitions in a `.tpp` file (or some other file ending) and include that in the header, but it's nothing more then a way to organize the code. The `.tpp` would still need to be exsposed to the third party user.

Comment: If for example `T` is limited to arithmetic type, this is feasible.